# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn not showing the context menu?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am trying to make a DataGridComboBoxColumn that has a static list to choose from:  Not Started, In Progress, Completed

Here is what I have in the XAML and while it builds fine I cannot see the options in the drop down:

```
           <DataGridComboBoxColumn  Header="Status" Width="auto"  IsReadOnly="False"  >
                <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,0,2" />
                    </Style>

                </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Not Started" />
                        <MenuItem Header="In Progress"  />
                        <MenuItem Header="Completed" />  
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work they way that other DataGrid.ContextMenu's work.  I feel like I'm missing something really easy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use CompositeCollection:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn  Header="Status" Width="auto"  IsReadOnly="False"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
                <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,0,2" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <sys:String>Not Started</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>In Progress</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>Completed</sys:String>
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Add the namespace:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: I like the way this looks, but is there a way to allow the selected value to remain in the cell?  After I click into a different cell the value goes away.

Comment: Yes, add a selected item and bind it. I will update the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to have a default binding to a value from a database?  So show the current value, but allow the user to select a new value?

Answer (score 0):

`ContextMenuService` provides the system implementation for displaying a ContextMenu

What you want is not too far off from what you already had. Its tested and works for me:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn  Header="Status" Width="auto"  IsReadOnly="False"  >
    <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,0,2" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Not Started" />
                        <MenuItem Header="In Progress"  />
                        <MenuItem Header="Completed" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Currently set to work for cell clicking but can be easily set to Header or both.

Comment: This works but when I click on the value it never shows in the cell.

Comment: This works, and probably answers my question in a very direct way, but I didn't realize it was going to display the context menu the way I was originally going about it, but this does indeed work too!